# Django display icon if all fields are filled in

Tags: python, django

I currently have this view that's simpy a `ListView`, but I would like to display if the object has all its fields filled in.

```
class ExampleList(ListView):
    model = Example
    template_name = 'example.html'
```

Example.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class='col-md-12'>
  {% for example in object_list %}
    <p><a href="{% url 'example_update' example.id %}">{{ example }}</a></p>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

So the example ofcourse has a few fields (think like image fields, mandatory and non-mandatory ones, name etc)

How would I display a 'X' or 'V' icons before it if all the fields are filled in or not? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could add a [class method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#model-methods) on the `Example` model that returns `True` when all fields are not empty, e.g.:

```
class Example(models.Model):

    ... # Attribute definitions

    def is_complete(self):
        # Write code to return True if all fields are filled in
```

Call that method from your template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class='col-md-12'>
  {% for example in object_list %}
    <p>
        {% if example.is_complete %}V{% else %}X{% endif %}
        <a href="{% url 'example_update' example.id %}">{{ example }}</a
    </p>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like a good one indeed, will put some work intot this. Thank you